# converting into string in linq to entites

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Here `DisplayName` is of type `string`, `foo` is object. When I use `foo.ToString()`, it throws an error.

I have the code:

```
var completionTimeModels =
    from timeline in context.processTimelines
    join asst in context.timeKeeping on timeline.Id equals asst.Id into TT
    from TimeModels in TT.DefaultIfEmpty()

    let foo = TimeModels.ExternalId !=null ? TimeModels.Name: timeline.circuitName
    select new Items()
    {
        Name = timeline.Name
        DisplayName = foo
    };
```

and when I do the following:

```
DisplayName = TimeModels.ExternalId !=null ? TimeModels.Name.ToString(): timeline.circuitName.ToString(),
```

it gives an error:

> Linq cannot handle .ToString()

Comment: You explicitly invoke ToString() methods on TimeModels.Name and timeline.circuitName, so it seems they're not strings. If so, what are their types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToString()` is not defined for Linq to Entities - you can project to an anonymous class, then switch to Linq to Objects for the final projection:

```
    (...
    select new 
    { 
        Name = timeline.Name, 
        DisplayName = TimeModels.ExternalId !=null ? TimeModels.Name : timeline.circuitName
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x=> new Items()
     {
              Name = x.Name
              DisplayName = x.DisplayName.ToString()
     };
```

Why do you have to do this in the first place though? What type are `TimeModels.Name` and `timeline.circuitName` ?

Comment: in the first select  DisplayName = TimeModels.ExternalId !=null ? TimeModels.Name : timeline.circuitName
   gives the error as DisplayName is string..

Comment: What type are they in your model, not in the database? - if they are varchar then they *should* be mapped to a string property in the Entities model.

Comment: I edited the question..TimeStatus and TimeLineStatus are navigation properties  set in edmx.. is there anyother i can do this.. can't i do with Let keyword..what if i declare DisplayName as object

Comment: You still didn't say which type they are in your model. They are navigation properties **of what type** ?

Comment: I created enum of statuses TimeModels.ExternalID!= null ? Enum.ToObject(typeof(Shared.Statuses), TimeModel.Id).Tostring() : Enum.ToObject(typeof(Shared.Statuses), TimeLine.Id).Tostring(),  ..did this way give the same error about string..

Comment: And what would their string representation be? You can't just convert an entity into a string, you have to pick a property

Comment: Thanks your answer worked..suppose if i declare Object DisplayName then can we bind this to telerikGrid or i need to convert it